# Why does the error method return an error?

Tags: xtext, xtend

I want to validate input corresponding to the following grammar snippet:

```
Declaration:
    name = ID "=" brCon=BracketContent
;

    BracketContent:
        decCon=DecContent (comp+=COMPARATOR content+=DecContent)*
    ;

        DecContent:
            (neg=("!"|"not"))? singleContent=VarContent (op+=OPERATOR nextCon+=VarContent)*
        ;
```

My validation looks like that:

```
  @Check
  def checkNoCycleInHierarchy(Declaration dec) {
    if(dec.decCon.singleContent.reference == null) {
        return
    }

    var names = newArrayList

    var con = dec.decCon.singleContent

    while(con.reference != null) {
        con = getThatReference(con).singleContent

        if(names.contains(getParentName(con))) {
            val errorMsg = "Cycle in hierarchy!"
            error(errorMsg, 
                SQFPackage.eINSTANCE.bracketContent_DecCon,
                CYCLE_IN_HIERARCHY)

            return
        }

        names.add(getParentName(con))
    }
  }
```

But when I test this validation with a testCaseit returns me an error message:

```
Expected ERROR 'raven.sqf.CycleInHierarchy' on Declaration at [-1:-1] but got
ERROR (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl@5a7fe64f (name: Declaration) (instanceClassName: null) (abstract: false, interface: false).0) 'Error executing EValidator', offset null, length null
ERROR (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EClassImpl@5a7fe64f (name: Declaration) (instanceClassName: null) (abstract: false, interface: false).0) 'Error executing EValidator', offset null, length null
```

I just can't figure out what's wrong with it so I hope that someone of you might have an idea.

Greetings Krzmbrzl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it was an internal error...I'm still not exactly sure what went wrong but I have rewritten my validation method and now it works as expected.
Now the method looks like this:

```
enter code here@Check
  def checkNoCycleInHierarchy(Declaration dec) {
    if(dec.varContent.reference == null) {
        //proceed only if there is a reference
        return
    }

    var content = dec.varContent

    var names = newArrayList

    while(content.reference != null && !names.contains(getParentName(content))) {
        names.add(getParentName(content))
        content = content.reference.varContent

        if(names.contains(getParentName(content))) {
            val errorMsg = "Cycle in hierarchy!"
            error(errorMsg,
                SQFPackage.eINSTANCE.declaration_BrCon,
                CYCLE_IN_HIERARCHY)

                return
        }
    }
  }
```

I have the suspicion that there was a problem with the usage of my "getThatReference" in this case.

Greeting Krzmbrzl

Answer (score 1):

You test utility tells you that the validator did not produce the expected validation error ("CycleInHierarchy"). 
Instead, the validator produced the error "Error executing EValidator".
Which means an exception has been thrown when your validator was executed.

Comment: Should have mentioned it in my question that you found  that out already... My question is rather about the reason of the exception... Thank you anyway